# Error in SELECT DISTINCT command in db2 when pasting the SQL script

Tags: sql, select, db2, distinct

I have this error when I paste my SQL script on the db2 command line,

> SQL3022N  An SQL error "-104" occurred while processing the SELECT
>   string in  the Action String parameter.
>
> SQL0104N  An unexpected token "car.ID as "Car ID", car.SPEED as "S" 
>   was found following "SELECT DISTINCT ".  Expected tokens may include: 
>   "(space)".  SQLSTATE=42601

this is my SQL script:

EXPORT TO car.csv OF DEL SELECT DISTINCT car.ID as "Car ID", car.SPEED as "Car SPEED", ..

I am not really sure what the error is. I've been deleting stuffs on my code too to check if it would change the error, but it's still the same. What might be wrong on this?

Comment: Don't know about db2, but it seems that it doesn't support spaces in alias. Try `"Car\ ID"`. Btw, a tag `mysql` is unnecessary here.

Comment: Michael, thanks for that, I tried it. The error is still the same.

SQL0104N An unexpected token "car.ID as "Car\ ID" ..

Comment: Try Car_ID and Car_Speed

Comment: Yep, tried it, still the same error. I also tried deleting the as "Car ID", and as "Car SPEED", the error is still the same, 

SQL0104N  An unexpected token "car.ID, car.SPEED" 
was found following "SELECT DISTINCT ".  Expected tokens may include:  
"<space>".  SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: Then post your table structure ad full query.

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the

> "

liKe in my example here:

```
db2 "export to test.del of del select empno as \"Employee Number\" from employee "
```

Comment: This shows up.

'SQL3022N  An SQL error "-7" occurred while processing the SELECT string in the 
Action String parameter.

SQL0007N  The character "\" following "DISTINCT car.ID as" is not valid.  
SQLSTATE=42601'

Comment: Did you enclose the statements in " "? Which OS?

Comment: Yeah, I did. after db2 "export ... ; " My OS is RHEL 7.3.

Comment: The full query would be helpful - as mentioned above. Are you running it from a shell?

Answer (score 0):

The error is from your assigned column names:

change: 
Car ID     => Car_ID

Car SPEED  => Car_SPEED

`EXPORT TO car.csv OF DEL SELECT DISTINCT car.ID as Car_ID , car.SPEED as Car_SPEED, ..`